# How can I use this code on frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I trying to make bouncing balls.I use this [example:](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/06/07/managing-multiple-balls-collisions-with-flash-as3-version/)

But I don't work on class files, and I'm trying to use as frame code.Here is what I do so far.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import Ball;

var nSpeedX:Number;
var nSpeedY:Number;

var nStageWidth:Number = 500;
var nStageHeight:Number = 400;

var NSpeedX:Number;
var NSpeedY:Number;


var mcBallContainer:MovieClip;

var MCBallA:MovieClip;
var MCBallB:MovieClip;

var nNumBalls:Number = 1;


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BallCollision);
function BallCollision(oly:Event) {

    mcBallContainer = new MovieClip ( ) ;
            mcBallContainer.x = mcBallContainer.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(mcBallContainer);

            this.addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler );

            for (var i = 0; i < nNumBalls; i++) 
            {
                var mcBall:Ball = new Ball ( Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 1 ) - 4 ), Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 12 ) - 4 ) );
                mcBall.x = Math.random() * nStageWidth;
                mcBall.y = Math.random() * nStageHeight;
                mcBallContainer.addChild ( mcBall );
            }
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BallCollision) //Fixed
}

function enterFrameHandler(oly:Event) {

    for ( var i = 0; i < mcBallContainer.numChildren; i++ ) 
            {
                var mcBall1:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( i );

                for ( var j = i + 1; j < mcBallContainer.numChildren; j++ )
                {
                    var mcBall2:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( j );

                    var nDistX:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.x - mcBall2.x );
                    var nDistY:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.y - mcBall2.y );
                    var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );

                    if ( nDistance < 20 )
                    {
                        solveBalls ( mcBall1, mcBall2 );
                    }
                }
}


//

function solveBalls ( MCBallA:MovieClip, MCBallB:MovieClip ) : void{



            var nX1:Number = MCBallA.x;
            var nY1:Number = MCBallA.y;
            var nDistX:Number = MCBallB.x - nX1;
            var nDistY:Number = MCBallB.y - nY1;

            var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );
            var nRadiusA:Number = MCBallA.width/2;
            var nRadiusB:Number = MCBallB.width/2;
            //var nRadius:Number = 10;

            var nNormalX:Number = nDistX/nDistance;
            var nNormalY:Number = nDistY/nDistance;

            var nMidpointX:Number = ( nX1 + MCBallB.x )/2;
            var nMidpointY:Number = ( nY1 + MCBallB.y )/2;

            MCBallA.x = nMidpointX - nNormalX * nRadiusA;
            MCBallA.y = nMidpointY - nNormalY * nRadiusA;
            MCBallB.x = nMidpointX + nNormalX * nRadiusB;
            MCBallB.y = nMidpointY + nNormalY * nRadiusB;

            var nVector:Number = ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedX - MCBallB.nSpeedX ) * nNormalX )+ ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedY - MCBallB.nSpeedY ) * nNormalY );
            var nVelX:Number = nVector * nNormalX;
            var nVelY:Number = nVector * nNormalY;

            MCBallA.nSpeedX -= nVelX;
            MCBallA.nSpeedY -= nVelY;
            MCBallB.nSpeedX += nVelX;
            MCBallB.nSpeedY += nVelY;
}

}
```

My code is working but balls number More than it should be.And balls is not collision each other. What is wrong of my code ??

UPDATED Thanks @Organis

Comment: Your loops are wrong. I guess you are trying to use **for** loop, but you actually forgot to use **for** keyword.

Comment: I updated code but result are same.

Comment: Ok, let's see. Every frame you call **BallCollision** and create a new container full of balls. So every frame you try to check balls for collisions, you check the new container and never get back to it, so the balls in the lost container are left to themselves. I guess you want only one container of balls, so you should not call **BallCollision** every frame, just once is fine.

Comment: Thank you Organis I remove that event when after it happen.

stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BallCollision)